# Move "Cursor" of readObject (Stop reading the same object)

Tags: java, file, object, inputstream

There are 3 objects in the "or" file. The loop returns the same object over and over again and I do not know how to tell the readObject() to move onto the next object.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;



public class Mainclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int l = 1;
        
        while (l > 0) {
                
            try {
                
                InputStream is = new FileInputStream("or.rtf");
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
                Stone p = (Stone) ois.readObject();
                System.out.println(p);
                ois.close();
                
            }   catch(Exception e) {
                    if(e instanceof EOFException) {
                        l--;
                        System.err.println();
                    } else if(e instanceof FileNotFoundException) {
                        l--;
                        System.err.println(e);
                    } else {
                        System.err.println(e);
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: New code looks like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Mainclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        InputStream is;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream("or.rtf");
            
            ObjectInputStream ois;
            try {
                ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
                
                int l = 1;
                while (l > 0) {
                        
                    try {
                        
                        Stone p = (Stone) ois.readObject();
                        System.out.println(p);
                        ois.close();
                        
                    }   catch(Exception e) {
                            if(e instanceof EOFException) {
                                l--;
                                System.err.println();
                            } else if(e instanceof FileNotFoundException) {
                                l--;
                                System.err.println(e);
                            } else {
                                System.err.println(e);
                            }
                    }
                }
                    
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I get an IOException right from the start (Stream closed). I tried incorporating the advice given by moving the InputStream out of the loop and implementing the code for correct data into the "try" branches.

Comment: did you try to move the `InputStream ` outside of the while loop?

Comment: I won't let me as the exception check is missing then.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create only one `InputStream` and call the `readObject()` inside a while loop.

Comment: Then I get error messages as "is" and "ois"  may not have been initialized (In the ois.readobject line)

Comment: Moved the InputStream outside of the loop as suggested, sadly I now get an IOException. Edited the Post to reflect this.